# array.add with 3 arguments is not working in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
$checkStatuses = @{}
    $workflowInfo | ForEach-Object {
        $name = $_.name
        $status = $_.conclusion
        $updatedTime = $_.updated_at
        $checkStatuses.add($name, $status, $updatedTime)
    }
```

array.add with 2 values($name, $status) is working but when i add third value($updateTime) i am getting error. **Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "3".**

I am looking for an output something like a table. Ex: A dictionary with 3 columns

name   status    createdat
build  success   2022-11-01
run    failed    2022-11-02

Comment: ```$checkStatuses``` is a *hashtable*, not an array. Your ```add``` is creating a new entry in the hashtable that has a key ```$name``` and value ```$status``` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.add?view=net-7.0. It's not clear what you're expecting to happen when you call ```$checkStatuses.add($name, $status, $updatedTime)``` - could you explain what you're trying to do with that line of code?

Comment: If you run `$checkStatuses.add`, you can see there's no version of hashtable.add() with three arguments.

Comment: `$checkStatuses = $workflowInfo | Select-Object @{Name = 'name'; Expression = {$_.name}}, @{Name = 'status'; Expression = {$_.conclusion}}, @{Name = 'updatedTime'; Expression = {$_.updated_at}}`

Comment: @mclayton: Updated problem statement and required output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to add all the results to an array?

```
$checkStatuses = @()

$workflowInfo | ForEach-Object {
$checkStatuses += [PSCustomObject]@{
        $name = $_.name
        $status = $_.conclusion
        $updatedTime = $_.updated_at
    }
}
$checkStatuses
```

Comment: += kills puppies